# Collecting specific arguments

Tags: java, arrays, bukkit, collectors

I am developing a game plugin in java, and can't figure this out. I want to collect everything after `args[1]`. here is some of code so you can understand better.

```
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if(player.hasPermission("essentials.allow.kick")) {
            if(args.length == 0) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify player name.");
            }
            if(args.length == 1) {
                Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                if(!target.isValid()) {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "That player is not on server!");
                }else {
                    target.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "The kick reason has been told!");
                }
            }
            if(args.length > 1) {
                Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                if(!target.isValid()) {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "That player is not on server!");
                }
                else {
                    String message = Stream.of(args).skip(2).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
                    target.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It just outputs `[]`.

Comment: This line seems to do what you say you want: `String message = Stream.of(args).skip(2).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();`. Is anything the matter with it?

Comment: It just outputs [].

Comment: In that case your array has length 2; or the third element is the empty string, but that’s unlikely. You’re skipping 2 elements, so `[]` remains. If your array has length 3 or longer, you will have more output.

Comment: Looks like you are not doing anything with `args[1]`. Are you sure you wanted the arguments *after* `args[1]` or you wanted the arguments *starting* with `args[1]`? If the latter, you should only skip 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to collect all elements of an array after an n-th element, you can use the `subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` function of the `ArrayList` class. The documentation says:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

So you will need to convert your array into a `List` and then call the function `subList` on it.

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(args).sublist(1, args.length);
// Replace number 1 with the start index where you want to trim. (Inclusive)
```

Now if you want to convert that list to a String you can use the following function:

```java
public String buildMessage(List<String> list, String separator) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s: list) {
        sb.append(s).append(separator);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then call it by doing:

```java
String message = buildMessage(list, " "); // It will separate the arguments with spaces.
```

**Full demo**

```java
String[] args = new String[]{"Hi!", "I", "am", "a", "demo"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(args).sublist(1, args.length);
String message = buildMessage(list, " ");
System.out.println("Message: " + message);
```

Produced output:

```
Message: I am a demo
```

Let me know if this works for you!

**EDIT**

As stated in the comments by [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) you can simplify the full demo to:

**Full demo**

```java
String[] args = new String[]{"Hi!", "I", "am", "a", "demo"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(args).sublist(1, args.length);
String message = String.join(" ", list);
System.out.println("Message: " + message);
```

Then you will not need the `buildMessage` method.

Comment: Great! If my answer solved you issue, please mark it as the solution.

Comment: This `buildMessage` method is obsolete. You can just use `String message = String.join(" ", list);`